# NPM fails to install types

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, npm-install

I have a problem with npm install, in that it won't install @types.

This works fine

```
npm install --save lodash
```

However asking for types does not

```
npm install --save @types/lodash

PS C:\Development\Temp> npm install --save @types/lodash
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://github.com/types/lodash)
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git@github.com:types/lodash)
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/lodash Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-types-lodash-9eb5372a'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/lodash Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/lodash fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/lodash
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/lodash Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/lodash and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install types/lodash
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Development\Temp\types\lodash'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\npm\\tools\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "@types/lodash"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Development\Temp
npm ERR! node -v v8.6.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path C:\Development\Temp\types\lodash
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Development\Temp\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
PS C:\Development\Temp>
```

This has got me scratching my head. I've updated Chocolatey, NodeJS, NPM to make sure their own the latest versions. Tried the commands on empty folders or an existing TypeScript project - thinking it might be getting confused being ran within a Git repository (error: remote.origin.url). Looking at the GitHub URL it makes no sense git://github.com/types/lodash

I took these examples from [MSDN Blog - The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Update: I've uninstalled Node.js and tried reinstalling v6.11.3 LTS or v8.6.0. However the @types command still fails.

Update 2: I've realised Chocolately was masking the npm version. I removed the Chocolately folder, and upgraded npm as per @Louis answer.

Comment: It looks like you are required to have a github account with a private key configured in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes, but the URL itself is wrong github.com/types/lodash???

Comment: Works fine for me, have you tried to update npm?

Comment: Try to downgrade.

Comment: When all else fails, delete `node_modules/` and then `npm install`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade your `npm` version to version 4 or 5. I'm mentioning 4 because I ran into problems with 5, and using 4 is still viable. I don't know of any good reason to run an older version.

You are using `npm` version 1.4.9, as shown in this line of the log:

```
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
```

The problem is that **`npm` versions prior to version 2 do not support scoped packages**. Packages that begin with an `@` are scoped packages, so `@types/lodash` is a scoped package. You need `npm` version 2 or greater to install it. If you were to use the latest `npm` in the 1.x series (1.4.29), you'd get a better error message:

```
npm ERR! Error: This version of npm doesn't support scoped packages (caused by reference to @types/lodash). Update to npm@2+.
```

Version 1.4.9 did not even know that scoped packages were a thing, so it cannot give a nice error message. It looks like it took the `@` symbol as signifying that the package name is an address and filled in the missing information with Github as the default host.

The upgrade command I typically use to upgrade `npm` is:

```
npm install -g npm
```

You can specify a specific version by replacing the `npm` argument with one that gives specific version number. `npm@4`, for instance, would install the latest `npm` in the 4.x series. If you don't specify a version number, you get the latest released version.

Comment: Also note to install typings in `devDependencies`